# Division of elements in vector in c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl

I have vector in c++ something like `std::vector<double> v = {10.0, 5.0, 2.0}`. I want to divide the all the elements of the vector sequentially i.e 10/5.0 =2.0 and then 2.0/2.0 which should be 1. So, the final answer is the division of all elements of the vector. Is there any way to this efficiently using some STL function or algorithm. I do not want to use `for` loop. Thanks for the help!!

Comment: I tried to use std::divide<double> like this std::accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), 1.0, std::divides<double>())). But i got wrong result.

Comment: What if the vector is empty?

Comment: Are you looking for [std::partition](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition) ?

Comment: Then do nothing. just throw an error

Comment: @DhruvinNaik Such call would be equivalent to `1.0 / 10.0 / 5.0 / 2.0`, given your example. Did you try something like `std::accumulate(v.begin() + 1, v.end(), *v.begin(), std::divides<double>()))` (assuming non-empty vector)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As **@Algirdas Preidžius** mentioned in a comment (I started to write my answer before it popped), you probably just missed the fact that the algorithm should start with the first number and **not** divide by it. This should be what you're expecting:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<double> vec = {10, 5, 2};

    std::cout << std::accumulate(vec.cbegin() + 1, vec.cend(),
                                 vec[0], std::divides<>());
}
```

Notice the `+ 1` after `vec.cbegin()` and `vec[0]` as the starting value